# Geometric intuition for harmonic conjugate functions

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

It is known that given a harmonic function $u$ of class $C ^ {2}$ defined in a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ , we can find a function $v$ also harmonic, such that $f = u + iv$,  is a holomorphic function.

- What does this definition mean geometrically?
- Would there be applications of this in physics?

Comments or references, are very welcome!!

Comment: One physics application is that for irrotational 2D fluid flow, the flow can be characterized by either a stream function or a velocity potential, which are harmonic conjugates of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Contours of constant $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ will be crossing orthogonally. For example, the harmonic conjugate of $x$ is $y$.